# Signalr implementation in mvc

Tags: signalr

I have few charts to render in the UI. The data has been populated from multiple tables using a web API service. Whenever a change in the data, I get a notification in the web API service. My question is that, is it possible use signalr to refresh data real-time.
Is it possible to invoke a signalr client methods from the web API service? Your help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to invoke client methods from outside the hub. You need to use `GlobalHost` to do that. You can find more details in the [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-server#callfromoutsidehub).